# autocomplete + elasticsearch + symfony2

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I'm on symfony 2.2 + FoqElasticaBundle

I try to use autocomplete from a result query elasticsearch

```
<input type="text" class="span3" id="search" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" />

var subjects = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'];
$('#search').typeahead({source: subjects})
```

autocomplete works like this, but...

How to get my elasticsearc url replace the subjects like this?

```
var subjects = "http://myhost:9200/_search?pretty=true";
```

I want that the source of my autocomplete is the result of my query elasticsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With typeahead you can use the data coming from the server like:

```
function search() {
    $('#search').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.get("{{path("url_to_fetch_from_server", {_format: "json"})}}", { "query" : query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
};

$(function(){
    search();
});
```

As you can see the typeahead source function take 2 arguments.

- query is the text type in the typeahead box. you need to pass this to the server
- process is the callback.

The server should response back in JSON format. you can replace "{{path("url_to_fetch_from_server", {_format: "json"})}}" to your real url.

```
public function queryAction(){
    $query = $this->getRequest()->query->get("query");
    $gType = $this->container->get('foq_elastica.finder.search_db');


    $results = $gType->find($query, 20);

    $tools = [];
    foreach($results as $result){
         $tools[] = $result->getTool();
    }

    return new Response(json_encode($tools));

}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, but i don't understand the process callback. And what is the method getTool ? I replace it with my method who call my title.On the callbakc process, i don't have my result, only the same result: the 10 first.It seem that my queryAction in the controller isn't execute

Comment: @channa ly can you please add the route ?